# Trying to get not greedy regex in omake

Tags: regex, makefile, regex-greedy, omake

im working in a omake file and have a string represented a path.
I'm trying to remove the first directory.

this is my string:

```
PATH = \PI\Common\noa\common\util
```

i wrote this regex:

```
$(PATH,S/.+\\\(.*\)/\1/)
```

but the result is util.
While what I want to receive is this string : `\Common\noa\common\util`

i tried using `"?"` for being not greedy but it doesn't work here (omake file)

someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the non-greedy modifier doesn't work in omake, you can always explicitly prevent the backslash from matching in your "get everything up to the second backslash" expression:

`\\[^\]+\(.*\)`

I don't know if the brackets have to be escaped in omake, but you get the idea...